# Opencart вывод из вложенных циклов foreach в разные блоки

Tags: php, opencart, foreach

Пытаюсь сделать меню с категориями, суб-категориями и суб-суб-категориями. Столкнулся с проблемой — не получается вывести результат вложенного цикла в другой div.

Вот такой код:

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category_1) { ?>
  <?php if ($category_1['children']) { ?>
  <li>
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $category_1['name']; ?></a>
    <div class="megamenu">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <?php foreach ($category_1['children'] as $category_2) { ?>
        <a class="child_cat__a" href="<?php echo $category_2['href']; ?>"  data-name="<?php echo $category_2['name']; ?>">
          <div class="child_cat"><?php echo $category_2['name']; ?></div>
        </a>
      <?php foreach($category_2['children'] as $category_3) { ?>
        <div class="col-md-9" data-name="<?php echo $category_3['name']; ?>">
          <a href="<?php echo $category_3['href']; ?>"><span><?php echo $category_3['name']; ?></span></a>
        </div>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php } ?>
      </div>
      </div>
  </li>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
```

Здесь у меня выводится все, что нужно, но подряд.

Хотел сделать так:

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category_1) { ?>
  <?php if ($category_1['children']) { ?>
  <li>
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $category_1['name']; ?></a>
    <div class="megamenu">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <?php foreach ($category_1['children'] as $category_2) { ?>
        <a class="child_cat__a" href="<?php echo $category_2['href']; ?>"  data-name="<?php echo $category_2['name']; ?>">
          <div class="child_cat"><?php echo $category_2['name']; ?></div>
        </a>
      <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <?php foreach($category_2['children'] as $category_3) { ?>
        <div class="col-md-9" data-name="<?php echo $category_3['name']; ?>">
          <a href="<?php echo $category_3['href']; ?>"><span><?php echo $category_3['name']; ?></span></a>
        </div>
      <?php } ?>
      </div>
  </li>
  <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
```

...но в таком случае выводится только самая первая суб-суб-категория.

Сразу прошу прощения за нубский вопрос, и прошу хотя бы подсказать, как из вложенного лупа можно вывести результат в отдельный div в tpl-файле.

Заранее благодарю )